# BASH script works flawless in Cygwin, crashes when launched from Jenkinses "Execute shell"

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I have a problem with Jenkins. I have a loop like this (embedded in a for...do..done loop)

```
var=$(head $file | grep ERROR)

if [ ! -z "$var" ]; then
  echo "Some error message"
  .././converter.sh $file $file.TMP $file.ERR.txt
  RESULT=$(expr $RESULT + 10)
fi
```

This loop is working perfectly when launched from Cygwin, but is crashing when launched on Jenkins... All the information Jenkins spits out of his mouth:

```
08:55:50 + for file in '*.DATA'
08:55:50 ++ grep ERROR
08:55:50 ++ head TESTFILE_1.DATA
08:55:50 + var=
08:55:50 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
08:55:50 Archiving artifacts
```

Comment: I cannot see any relationship between both codes (the `bash` script and the Jenkins output).

Comment: If the problem resides on the Jenkins, why have you tagged this question about `bash`?

Comment: @Jdamian cause Jenkins is running the bash script. And the bash script is working under cygwin, and its not working under the Jenkins shell.

Comment: I suspect Jenkins checks the return code of the shell script to see if running it was successful, and that you didn't do that when running it yourself. Try running it in the shell and `echo $?` afterwards. If you get anything but `0`, there's your problem -- that's signalling an error.

Comment: Pay attention on the 4th line of the Jenkins output: `var` is empty THEN the commands inside the IF-THEN clause are not executed. Therefore, the error message shown in last lines are not due to: 1) other commands below the `fi` 2) Jenkins watchs out the return code of the shell script and reports an error message (do what Wintermute asked)

Answer (score 2):

When run under Jenkins with Execute Shell (from the help document of the Execute Shell build step):

> By default, the shell will be invoked with the "-ex" option. So all of the commands are printed before being executed, and the build is considered a failure if any of the commands exits with a non-zero exit code. Again, add the #!/bin/... line to change this behavior.

To reiterate, this means that any errors (such as your grep exiting with an error code) will cause the script to exit prematurely with an error. Normally, when you execute this script, it probably succeeds because `set -e` is not the default.

Any easy test to determine whether this is indeed the problem is to set the first line of the Execute Shell script to `#!/bin/sh -x`